# How to plot a line chart by considering first row labels as x-axis (in my case 01-02-2018 - 30-03-2018 should be as x axis label)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple lines in one chart for the following dataset.

| ID | 01-02-2018 | 02-02-2018 | 03-02-2018 | .... | 29-03-2018 | 30-03-2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.6 | ---- | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| ID_2 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.5 | ---- | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| ID_3 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.4 | ---- | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| ID_4 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.4 | ---- | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| ID_5 | 0.8 | 0.4 | 0.3 | ---- | 0.6 | 0.8 |

In my plot, Dates should be displayed on the X-axis and a single graph should contain the line chart for ID1 to ID5. I tried different solutions but did not get the desired plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do a transpose of you dataframe:

```
data={"01-02-2018":[0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1],"02-02-2018":[1,1.2,1.8,3,2],
    "03-02-2018":[4,3.2,0.8,1,6],"04-02-2018":[1,1.2,1.8,3,2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

dft=df.transpose()
dft.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

result:
[image]